Rasa falls into fallback zone everytime while running into docker container
When I trained the model on my local PC, it ran perfectly. However, when I tried running it in a Docker container after installing all dependencies, I encountered a fallback error everytime.
Here is the version details:
Compatible Version: 3.5.0 
Rasa SDK Version : 3.6.2 
Python Version : 3.8.18

Here is my config file:

# Configuration for Rasa NLU.
language: en

policies:
  - name: MemoizationPolicy
    priority: 3
  - name: RulePolicy
    priority: 1
    core_fallback_threshold: 0.3
    core_fallback_action_name: "action_default_fallback"
    enable_fallback_prediction: True

pipeline:
  - name: SpacyNLP
    model: "en_core_web_md"
  - name: SpacyEntityExtractor
    dimension: ["NAME"]
  - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
    intent_split_symbol: "+"
  - name: RegexFeaturizer
  - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
    analyzer: word
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
    analyzer: char_wb
    min_ngram: 1
    max_ngram: 4
  - name: LanguageModelFeaturizer
    model_name: "bert"
    model_weights: "bert-base-uncased"
  - name: DucklingEntityExtractor
    url: "http://localhost:8000"
    dimensions:
      - time
      - phone_number
      - email
      - name
      - number
  - name: DIETClassifier
    epochs: 150
    constrain_similarities: true
    entity_recognition: true
    entity_roles: true
    entity_groups: true
  - name: components.address_city_state_detector.AddressCityStateDetector
  - name: RegexEntityExtractor
    use_lookup_tables: true
    use_regexes: true
    use_word_boundaries: true
  - name: EntitySynonymMapper
  - name: FallbackClassifier
    threshold: 0.6
    ambiguity_threshold: 0.1

